# Multiple where clause with OR query for firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, where-clause

I want to implement two where clauses in my flutter firestore query, so that they work as OR function. If any of the queries is true I want the result to show.

Comment: could you elaborate more about your problem?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation states, Firestore DOES NOT HAVE an `OR` operation on `where` clauses.  The closest you can come is 'in', which will check a single field against an array of values (up to 10 values).  Otherwise, you will have to issue multiple queries and combine them in your application.

Please see current [query operators supported](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators).